# HSQLDB turn into DB2 syntax

Tags: db2, hsqldb

I am using hsqldb for junits on springn jdbc project and url is

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:${basedir}/src/test/resources/hsqldb/test.db;sql.syntax_db2=true.
```

Even though passing sql.syntax_db2=true, SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX DB2 FALSE statement has been creating on persistant file.So I need to make SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX DB2 TRUE

Could pleas help on the same.
Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

The DB2 syntax compatibility is turned on internally but it is not peristed in the .script file due to a bug. The workaround is to enable ORACLE syntax compatibility as well, then both get persisted.

This bug will be fixed in HSQLDB version 2.3.3.